# Execute sudo command in ubuntu from java class

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, terminal, sudo

I have a sh file which conatins a many sudo commands, say a script as below:

```
test.sh

#!/bin/sh
sudo apt-get install gedit
sudo date --set="2014/02/20 10:00"
```

When I execute the test.sh from terminal it works fine. Problem is when I try to execute this file from a java class. The script doesn't execute. I tried this:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh","/home/priyatam/test.sh");
```

Does anyone have an idea to execute this sudo command from java class? Please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as the script will be outputting the prompt to the screen, it will be necessary to capture the processes inputstream

```
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();
```

I would also recommend using

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/home/user/test.sh");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
```

Comment: I am not getting any prompt even

Comment: to be honest I would start off with a shell, not the script.  Have a look at this link  http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/getting-started-with-javas-processbuilder-a-sample-utility-class-to-interact-with-linux-from-java-program/